# Live Search results from database using AJAX, JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

my script returns an array of JSON, and not individual results from the database. The script is designed to retrieve from the database records that match the text you typed. Below my codes, what could be wrong?

PHP:

```
//after connect to database (succesfull)
if($_GET['search_data'])
{
    $search = ltrim($_GET['search']);
    $limit = 15;
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset={$charset}");

    $res = $conn->query("SELECT aid, name FROM titles WHERE LIKE '%".$search."%'");
    $data = array();
    while($row = $res->fetch_accoss())
    {
        $row['name'] = htmlspecialchars_uni($row['name']);
        $data[] = array('id' => $row['aid'], 'text' => $row['name']);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search").keyup(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php?get=search_data",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: "text=" + text,
                async: false,
                success: function(text) {
                    if(text)
                    {
                            $('#display').append(JSON.stringify(text))
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#display').append('No results!');
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    });</script>
        <title>Live search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        search: <input type="textbox" value="" name="search" placeholder="Write here..." id="search" />
        <br />
        <div id="display"></div>
</html>
```

and results:

```
[{"id":"10","text":"Dropdowns"},{"id":"9","text":"Accordions"},{"id":"5","text":"Convert Weights"},{"id":"3","text":"Animated Buttons"},{"id":"8","text":"Side Navigation"},{"id":"6","text":"Parallax"},{"id":"2","text":"HTML Includes"},{"id":"7","text":"Progress Bars
"},{"id":"4","text":"Top Navigation"},{"id":"1","text":"Range Sliders"},{"id":"11","text":"Google Maps"}]
```

My problem is that it shows when you type some letters the whole array of JSON, and not only the record, which we expect. What can I do?

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? If you want an answer, you'll need to explain the problem/error.

Comment: @SloanThrasher My problem is that it shows when you type some letters the whole array of JSON, and not only the record, which we expect. What can I do?

Comment: In the ```success``` function, you need to use the JSON data to generate valid HTML before you put it into the ```#display``` element. You can do this on the PHP side before returning it, IOW return HTML instead of JSON, or you can do it in your JavaScript in the success function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying go get the search parameter with **$_GET['search']** you need to use **$_POST['text']**. Try this :

```
if($_GET['search_data'])
    {
        $search = ltrim($_POST['text']);
        $limit = 15;
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset={$charset}");
    if(!empty($search)
        $res = $conn->query("SELECT aid, name FROM titles WHERE LIKE '%".$search."%'");
        $data = array();
        while($row = $res->fetch_accoss())
        {
            $row['name'] = htmlspecialchars_uni($row['name']);
            $data[] = array('id' => $row['aid'], 'text' => $row['name']);
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }
```

And it's a good practice to use object in your ajax data

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").keyup(function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php?get=search_data",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    text: text
                },
                async: false,
                success: function (text) {
                    if (text)
                    {
                        $('#display').append(JSON.stringify(text))
                    } else
                    {
                        $('#display').append('No results!');
                    }
                }

            });
        });
    });
```